# How to sum a group of rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table looking like this

```
 ID   Customer       TimeStamp          Occ
14488   5130    2016-05-11 11:16:52.740 3
114304  5130    2016-05-11 11:01:51.263 3
114156  5130    2016-05-11 10:46:49.943 3
113971  5130    2016-05-11 10:31:49.857 5
113790  5130    2016-05-11 10:16:49.510 6
113605  5130    2016-05-11 10:01:48.643 1
113419  5130    2016-05-11 09:46:46.843 3 
113234  5130    2016-05-11 09:31:46.643 2
113052  5130    2016-05-11 09:16:45.403 2
112867  5130    2016-05-11 09:01:44.193 9
112681  5130    2016-05-11 08:46:42.220 8
112493  5130    2016-05-11 08:31:38.327 3
112305  5130    2016-05-11 08:16:37.220 2
112122  5130    2016-05-11 08:01:37.147 8
111936  5130    2016-05-11 07:46:35.933 5
111747  5130    2016-05-11 07:31:34.457 5
```

What I want to do is to merge the rows of this table, four by four, and sum the occurence of that. It would be great also if I could print the earliest and latest timestamps of the merged 4 rows. The output would be like this :

```
ID     Customer       Last TimeStamp        EarliestTimeStamp         Sum Occ
1   5130           2016-05-11 11:16:52.740  2016-05-11 10:31:49.857     14  //Sum of the first 4 rows   (3+3+3+5)                
2   5130           2016-05-11 10:16:49.510  2016-05-11 09:31:46.643     12 //Sum of the first 4 rows   (6+1+3+2)
```

Is there any way I could do that with SQL?

Comment: Add row_number() to query and group result by row number divided by 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query

```
SELECT ID, Customer, TimeStamp, Occ,
  (SELECT 1+FLOOR(COUNT(1)/4) FROM table1 it
    WHERE ot.Customer=it.Customer AND it.TimeStamp<ot.TimeStamp) AS seq
 FROM table1 as ot
```

Will add a sequence number - the first 4 are labelled 1, the next 4 labeled 2 etc. Note that the function FLOOR truncates the float to an integer - it might be called INT in your database.

```
 ID   Customer       TimeStamp          Occ   seq
14488   5130    2016-05-11 11:16:52.740 3     1
114304  5130    2016-05-11 11:01:51.263 3     1
114156  5130    2016-05-11 10:46:49.943 3     1
113971  5130    2016-05-11 10:31:49.857 5     1
113790  5130    2016-05-11 10:16:49.510 6     2
113605  5130    2016-05-11 10:01:48.643 1     2
113419  5130    2016-05-11 09:46:46.843 3     2
113234  5130    2016-05-11 09:31:46.643 2     2
```

You can then get the max and min and sum relatively easily:

```
SELECT seq, Customer, min(TimeStamp), max(TimeStamp), SUM(occ)
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Customer, TimeStamp, Occ,
    (SELECT 1+FLOOR(COUNT(1)/4) FROM table1 it WHERE ot.Customer=it.Customer and it.TimeStamp<ot.TimeStamp) AS seq
   FROM table1 as ot
) AS dt
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
with cte as
(
select row_number() over (partition by customer order by timestamp desc) as sNo,*
from tab
)
select customer,max(timestamp) as last_timestamp, min(timestamp) as EarliestTimeStamp, sum(occ) as  [Sum occ]
from cte
group by sno/4,customer
```

Comment: The grouping seems to have to be on timestamp, so you want to select row_number over(order by timestamp desc)

Comment: Easier like this than writing up a seperate answer :P